# Redirect to public/ in php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel

I have a laravel application that I made changes to the folder structure, I have been working with laragon and everything works fine but on my local environment and live server.

However, when i user php artisan serve, the generated url doesn't load assets in the public folder.

E.g

```
https://livewebsite.com // [live server] works.
https://myproject.local // [laragon] works.
http://localhost/myproject // [laragon /xampp] works
http://127.0.0.1:8000 // artisan [doesn't load assets, assets in the public directory returns 404
//e.g http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/assets/themes/cryptic/style/bgs.css  would return 404
```

Changes I made,

```
|-core
|-public
|-.htaccess
|-index.php
```

I have moved all laravel core folders and files  to the core folder,
moved the .htaccess and index.php to the root directory.

From my debugging so far, I understand that laravel built in server redirects requests to the public folder where the index.php file is located.

What changes can I make so that the request is not sent to the public folder,
i.e `http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/assets/themes/cryptic/style/bgs.css` should just be allowed to be without be redirected.

The entire thing works on various environments except when I'm using laravel built-in PHP server with the artisan command.

**EDIT**
Folder structure

```
|-project
    |-core 
      |-app
      |-bootstrap
      |-config
      |-database
      |-lang 
      |-etc
    |-public
      |-assets
    |-test-folder
      |-img.png
    |-.htacess
    |-index.php
```

in this setup, laravel `base_path()` is `project/core` . This where all laravel core files and folders are stored.

Now I have folder `test-folder` with an image `img.png` . If i go to `http://localhost/project/new-folder/img.png` it will return the image but if i go `http://127.0.0.1:8000/new-folder/img.png`  will return 404. If i use a live server and go `http://livewebsite.com/new-folder/img.png` , it loads.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to reputation, but what you're doing might be unsafe!

This way all your project files will be public, which can expose credentials and exposes Composer packages to the public as well. This means any PHP file in any Composer package can be executed, which can lead to remote code execution, which has happened before [here](https://twitter.com/IBBoard/status/992827870526525440) and is described [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/3112).

Comment: perhaps you misunderstand what I'm doing, only files in /public folder are css, js  and images, all laravel files are in the core folder.

let me modify and tag you

Comment: Just so I understand it correctly, when you publish this website, would assets be accessed from example.com/public/[asset] ? Because if that's the case, that means your index.php is on example.com/index.php, and your core files are in example.com/core/. The laravel files should not be exposed.

Comment: yes, check the edits

Comment: Is there also a `vendor` folder inside of core? If so: It's unsafe. Revert to the original folder structure. Generally I would recommend that anyway due to upgrades. You can access files you shouldn't if you go to `http://localhost/core/ [...] `.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out, perhaps i could use .htaccess to prevent direct access to all files and folders within /core/